# Bind form values in session bean

Tags: java, jsp, session, javabeans

i have a Bean stored in session, and three forms. I need save the submitted values to the bean, this is the sequence: <kbd>Form1.jsp</kbd> -> <kbd>Form2.jsp</kbd> -> <kbd>Form3.jsp</kbd> -> <kbd>ViewValues.jsp</kbd>.

This is my bean:

```
package bean;

public class Cotizacion implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // Some properties ...

    public Cotizacion(){
        // Nothing ...
    }
    // Accessors & toString ...
}
```

The first JSP have this action:

```
<jsp:useBean id="cotizacion" class="bean.Cotizacion" scope="session" />
```

The second and third JSP have this action:

```
<jsp:useBean id="cotizacion" class="bean.Cotizacion" scope="session">
    <jsp:setProperty name="cotizacion" property="*" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

When i try `<% System.out.print("Cobertura.jsp: " + cotizacion); %>` in the third form, the console output is:

> Cobertura.jsp: Ford;T;1990;5000;null;null;null;null;null;null

The bean is only populated after the first submit. The bean properties are same that the request params.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<jsp:setProperty name="cotizacion" property="*" />` reinitialized properties from request parameters, but you didn't use parameters or parameters are empty. Ensure the bean has getters and setters. If you remove this tag the bean should keep session values. If you want to populate the bean with parameters from the request then use

```
<jsp:useBean id="cotizacion" class="bean.Cotizacion" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty name="cotizacion" property="*" />
```

The above example results in iteration over the HTTP request parameters, matching bean property names with request parameter names and setting bean property values according to the corresponding request parameter values. If you submit the form using POST method you are missing parameters from the request.

Comment: Roman, the params exists in POST request. The setters are defined in the bean. If i remove the `<jsp:setProperty name="cotizacion" property="*" />` the bean never will be populated after each submit.

Comment: If you want to populate the bean with parameters from the request then see above code.

Comment: Glad that worked for you, with this parameters and properties meanings.